# Display the data in a html JSON array back to the user

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I was wondering if someone can help me

I am trying to make a User registration controller/model for a jquery mobile app with a PHP/MySQL database with the plan to put it through Adobe Phonegap.

I am doing all the development using Dreamweaver and a local WAMPserver, and I am passing info between the javascript/jquery and PHP using Ajax.

My problem is I am trying to do Ajax JSON call with a successful outcome printing a message onto the web page in the location

This is my class.controller.js

```
//Handler to trigger once a page is fully loaded
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    console.log('User Register Controller Linked');
    //Handler to deal with the RegisterUser Form submission
    $('#registerUser').submit(function() // this is a Listener Statement
    {   
        console.log("User Register Submit Button Clicked");

        //input collection
        var postData = $(this).serialize();

        console.log(postData);

        //user feedback - Loading Dialog
        $.mobile.loading('show',
        {
            text: 'Registering New Account - Please Wait',
            textVisible: true,
            theme: 'a'
        });

          //*****Ajax JSON call will SEND and RECEIVE data back from the model****
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            //dataType: "json", 
            data: postData,
            //Always have an external URL in an App
            url: 'http://myJourney/models/class.model.registerUser.php?action=register',

            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                //display the data in the html JSON array back to the user.         
                console.log(data.error);
                $('<div></div>').html(data.error).appendTo('.msg');

                $.mobile.loading('hide');
            },
            error: function()
            {
                alert('There was an error handling your registration!');
                $.mobile.loading('hide');         
            }
        });     
        return false;
    }); //close handler
});
```

The issue occurs at line 37, 
`$('<div></div>').html(data.error).appendTo('.msg');`.
The check on line 36, console.log(data.error); shows that data.error is undefined.

If I change it to 
`$('<div><p>Test</p></div>').html(data.error).appendTo('.msg');`. 
It prints out Test as expected.

The console log produced at line 34 is as follows

MySQL Connection Active!{"console.log":"firstN: test, lastN: test, email: test@test.com, PassWord: test, "}{"action":"login","html":"You Have Successfully Created The Account!","console.log":"INSERT INTO test VALUES ('0', 'test', 'test’, 'test@test.com', 'test')"}

All of this info comes from my 
class.model.php

```
<?php       
    /**
    * class.model.registerUser.php
    *
    * The purpose of the file is to register users of the website using their first name, last name, 
    * email address and password. This file uses JSON to encode data back to the controller.
    *
    * PHP version ?
    *
    * @author  
    * @version 
    */
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);

    include "class.model.common.php";
    DBConnect();

    $action = $_GET['action'];

    if($action=="register")
    {
            registerUser($ServerHost, $ServerUser, $ServerPassword, $DBName, $DBTable);    
    }

    function registerUser($ServerHost, $ServerUser, $ServerPassword, $DBName, $DBTable)
    {
        $Link = mysqli_connect($ServerHost, $ServerUser, $ServerPassword, $DBName);
        //COLLECT POST data
        $formValue=array();
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
        {
            $formValue[$key] = strip_tags($value);//remove html tags
            $formValue[$key] = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $value);//remove single quotes

            $testOutput = $testOutput.$key.": ".$formValue[$key].", ";

            if($formValue[$key]=="")
            {
                $message = "Please Fill In The Missing Field(s)!";
                echo json_encode(array('console.log'=>'missing data from the form','error'=>$message));
                exit();
            }//close missing field condition                
        }//close for each
        //Send Back Data To The Controller
        echo json_encode(array('console.log'=>$testOutput));

        $email = $formValue['email'];

        //Check if the owner has an email in the table - 
        $Query = "SELECT email FROM $DBTable WHERE email = '".$email."'";
        $Result = mysqli_query($Link, $Query);
        $Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result);
        $email_check = $Row['email'] ;    

        //If the owner already has data, do not allow them to add more!
        if( $email == $email_check)
        {
            $message = "Sorry, you have already created an account under this email address!";  
            //Send Back to the Controller
            echo json_encode(array('action'=>'error','html'=>$message));
            exit();    
        }
        else
        {
            //Match not found so carry on with the registration process

            $PassWord = $formValue['PassWord'];
            //Remove All Whitespace from the string
            $PassWord = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $PassWord);

            $Query = "INSERT INTO $DBTable VALUES ('0', '".$formValue['firstN']."', '".$formValue['lastN']."', '".$email."', '".$PassWord."')"; 

            //Has the query executed?                           
            if(mysqli_query($Link, $Query))
            {
                $message = "You Have Successfully Created The Account!";     
                //Send Back to the Controller
                echo json_encode(array('action'=>'login','html'=>$message, 'console.log'=>$Query));
            }//close insert query conditional 
        }//close email check conditional    
    }
?>
```

I want to get the String "You Have Successfully Created The Account!" out of data and into the .
Can someone explain how?

Thank you

Comment: don't add line numbers to your code in SO posts, makes it impossible for anyone to copy and replicate your issues

Comment: edited as suggested, thought it would make it easier to follow where in the code I was talking about. Thanks

Comment: can reference by what's on that line. Obviously we can't do the SQL queries but in cases where code can be tested the line numbers would be ugly to deal with

Comment: send back a consistent array structure. You don't have `error` as key in php array but you do have `data.action` and `data.html`. You can only make one `echo` of json per request. The `console.log` key sent from php will cause problems because it causes 2 echos and will cause overall response to be invalid